# unescape unicode string powershell

Tags: powershell, unicode, decode

In PowerShell, how do unescape the unicode escaped strings?

```
$str1 = "http:\u002f\u002fgoogle.com\u002fsomething\u002ftest"
```

to

```
http://google.com/something/test
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code to do this is:

```
[Regex]::Replace($str1, "\\[Uu]([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})", 
         {[char]::ToString([Convert]::ToInt32($args[0].Groups[1].Value, 16))} )
```